# foursquare and share checkin?

Tags: foursquare

Is it possible to create a checkin by allowing a user to click on button in a html page that takes them to a share location (checkin page)?

I am thinking- something like the twitter share url?

for example-

```
http://foursquare.com/share/?venue_id=12345
```

I want this functionality in order to allow users to swipe their nfc phone on a smart tag and it loads a html page with different options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On an Android-based or iOS-based mobile device, you can use special formed URLs in order to start the Foursquare application viewing the desired venue: https://developer.foursquare.com/resources/client

The URL https://m.foursquare.com/venue/#venue_id# (e.g. https://m.foursquare.com/venue/4b477346f964a520723226e3) can either be opened by the installed Android Foursquare App or opened by a normal browser (or other Intent receivers registered for that URL).

You can further use the URL https://foursquare.com/mobile/checkin?vid=#venue_id# to get to the mobile page, where you can just press "check in" or enter a shout. By checking-in via the mobile page (and not the app), you do not get points and are not able to earn Mayorships (see [Foursquare support](http://support.foursquare.com/entries/384200-i-can-t-use-the-app-on-my-phone-what-can-i-do-on-the-mobile-web)).

But you can, for example, create your own web app that accesses the Foursquare API and performs the check-in for the OAuth'ed users. By using the [HTML5 Geolocation](http://html5demos.com/geo) feature, you can also send the mobile device's Lat/Lon coordinates to your web app and perform valid check-ins that also count for Mayorships, etc. A good start is Foursquare's developer page: https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/

Comment: i have a particular interest in blackberrys on this one, thanks for the headsup though